# Transform a polynomial fit back into image-space

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image:

```
>>> image.shape
(720, 1280)
```

My image is a binary array of 0s and 255s.  I've done some cursory edge detection, and now I want to fit a polynomial through the points.

I want to see these points back on my original image, in image-space.

As far as I can tell, the standard way to do this is to unwrap the x,y- image with a reshape, fit on the unwrapped version, then re-reshape back into the original image.

```
pts = np.array(image).reshape((-1, 2))
xdata = pts[:,0]
ydata = pts[:,1]
z1 = np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 1) 
z2 = np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 2)  # or quadratic...
f = np.poly1d(z)
```

Now that I have this function, `f`, how do I use it to paint my lines in the original image space?

In particular:

1. What's the right inverse indexing of .reshape() to get back into image space?
2. This seems a bit cumbersome.  Is this reshape reshape dance a common thing in image processing?  Is what is described above the standard way to do this, or is there a different approach?
3. If mapping onto the 720, 1280, 1 array is called the image space, what is the reshaped space called?  data-space?  Linearized space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do this. You can combine [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), [`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) and [`np.polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) to do this. It would look like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# in your case, you would read your image
# > cv2.imread(...)  # import cv2 before
# but we are going to create an image based on a polynomial
img = np.zeros((400, 400), dtype=np.uint8)
h, w = img.shape
xs = np.arange(150, 250)
ys = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 0.01 * x**2 - 4*x + 600, xs))).astype(np.int)
img[h - ys, xs] = 255

# I could use the values I have, but if you have a binary image,
# you will need to get them, and you could do something like this
ys, xs = np.nonzero(img)  # use (255-img) if your image is inverted
ys = h - ys

# compute the coefficients
coefs = np.polyfit(xs, ys, 2)
xx = np.arange(0, w).astype(np.int)
yy = h - np.polyval(coefs, xx)

# filter those ys out of the image, because we are going to use as index
xx = xx[(0 <= yy) & (yy < h)]
yy = yy[(0 <= yy) & (yy < h)].astype(np.int) # convert to int to use as index

# create and display a color image just to viz the result
color_img = np.repeat(img[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
color_img[yy, xx, 0] = 255  # 0 because pyplot is RGB
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax[0].set_title('Binary')
ax[1].imshow(color_img)
ax[1].set_title('Polynomial')
plt.show()
```

The results look like this:

[image: Sample Polynomial]

If you print `coefs`, you will have `[ 1.00486819e-02 -4.01966712e+00  6.01540472e+02]` which are very close to the `[0.01, -4, 600]` we chose.